# Best practice for sharing table without inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, activerecord

**Situation**

I have four Rails models (A,B,C and D) that all have the same attributes (i.e. table storage needs). However, model D's behavior is radically different from the A,B and C and should not inherit any of the methods that A,B and C share. Right now my working inheritance hierarchy looks like:

**Inheritance Hierachy**

A < ActiveRecord :: Base

B < A

C < A

D < ActiveRecord :: Base

**Scope**

A has a default_scope: where("(type is null or type != 'D')")

D has a default_scope: where(type: 'D')

**Questions**

1. Why does D.new in the above scenario result in type "D"? I thought that this step would need to be explicit given that D doesn't inherit from A. Also how does Rails pick A to be the default model that gets type: nil when both inherit from ActiveRecord::Base?
2. Are there any fallacies in this approach that I should worry about? *I recognize 2 is a vague and open ended. The answer will be selected based only on 1.

Comment: Have you look at polymorphic http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: Have a code dive if you will [ActiveRecord::Inheritance](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb). To quote the proverbial MTV ("This is where the magic happens")

Comment: Why would you want to share the same table if they are not subtypes? It sounds like a lot of complexity just to avoid a few migrations?

Comment: I use to read `B < A` as *B is a A*. If `D` is not a special type of `A` then IMHO using STI would be an anti-pattern. Given all the magic that is related to STI in Rails, it would be much harder to fight Rails conventions than to duplicate a migration once to have two tables with a similar structure, but different names.

Comment: Yea, max / @spickermann, I agree with you guys. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Move the attributes to its own model (I don't know what the business case is, so lets just call it `Thing`)

```
A belongs to Thing
B belongs to Thing
C belongs to Thing
D belongs to Thing
```

This helps you to avoid two things often lead to confusion in Rails:

- Single Table Inheritance (STI): I.e. makes it harder to have DB level constraints as soon as there are differences between the types, URL generation, forms
- `default_scope` which often leads to confusing behavior when developers are not aware of it